# html submit button with php after not working

Tags: php, html, button, submit

I cannot seem to find an answer to my question on the internet.  I can't help but think it is a stupid mistake, however I have gone over my code at least 6 - 7 times and even took a break to look at it with fresh eyes.  If someone could look it over for me, that would be super sweet!

```
<div id="input_alignment" style="font-size:20px">

<?php 

if(!($Valid_Profile == true)){ ?>
    ...Form that has no issues
<?php }
else{ ?>

    <form action="Redact_Profiles.php" style="font-size:19px" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $Valid_Profile ?>" name="Valid_Profile" />
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $Username ?>" name="Username" />
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $Password ?>" name="Password" />

    <br />
    &emsp;&emsp; <?php echo $Profile_Username . "<br>"; ?>
    <input type="submit" style="font-size:9px" value="Edit" name="" />&ensp;<?php echo $Profile_Password . "<br>"; ?>
    <br />
    <br />
    ......<br />
    <input type="submit" style="font-size:9px" value="Edit" name="" />&ensp;<?php echo $Profile_First_Name . "<br>"; ?>
    <input type="submit" style="font-size:9px" value="Edit" name="" />&ensp;<?php echo $Profile_Last_Name . "<br>"; ?>
    &emsp;&emsp; <?php echo $Profile_EMail . "<br>"; ?>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" style="font-size:9px" value="Edit" name="" />&ensp;<?php echo $Profile_Location . "<br>"; ?>
    <input type="submit" style="font-size:9px" value="Edit" name="" />&ensp;<?php echo $Profile_Referee_Password . "<br>"; ?>
    <input type="submit" style="font-size:9px" value="Edit" name="" />
    </form>
<?php }

?>
</div>
```

The very last two submit buttons don't work.  When I take away the php containing the `$Profile_Location` and `$Profile_Referee_Password`, the submit buttons work.

Sorry, what I mean by *Doesn't work* means that the submit button isn't responding.  The page doesn't re-load, and it acts like the submit button is disabled.  The submit button looks enabled, but it is like it doesn't want to "press".

Comment: What's showing when you view the source where `$Profile_Location` and `$Profile_Referee_Password` should be echoed? It's possible you are getting an error that's breaking the markup.

Comment: Turn on your error reporting.

Comment: It looks like my code, with the exception of the php values being replaced by the values that they represent... if that makes sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After 2 days of headache I have figured it out: When a submit button is outside the bounds of the height and width of any "div", it will not function like a button, but more like a picture.  So as a good practice, when a button is not functioning properly, check to see if it is literally "outside" of the container you put it in.
This error doesn't present itself in viewing the source page, or in any error checking.  However, if it does, I don't know about it.  I am using a Mac, Safari 6, and CS5 Dreamweaver, if anyone is interested.